# What's the difference between following code?

Tags: python, algorithm, addition, multiplication

Currently Im solving and learning DSA. I'm using Coding Ninjas to learn DSA and for problems too.

[image: This is the question.]

so my question is what's the difference between following code?

```
def mul(m, n):
    if  m ==0  or n == 0:
        return 0
    return m * n
```

and

```
def mul(m, n):
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0
    return m + mul(m, n - 1)
```

whenever I submit my solution using the 2nd code, it shows that there was a problem 1 test case failed rest 5 complete, whereas in case of 1st code it's totally good 100% correct.

Comment: Please note the first snippet is not recursive, so it doesn't satisfy the task requirements. Additionally, it uses multiplication, which is not allowed (_"You can only use subtraction and addition..."_.)

Answer (score -1):

By default, Python's recursion limit is `1000`, and you run into this when `n >= 999`. To prevent this, add an additional `if` check.

```
def mul(m, n):
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return m
    return m + m + mul(m, n - 2)
```

This recurses in steps of 2, so when `n = 1000` it will recurse only 500 times.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that works (can't test, they don't allow Europeans, argh), but I really doubt that's intended. I'd expect the site to have increased the limit...

Comment: I couldn't think of any other reason for it to fail.

Comment: Yeah, me neither. Are you able to test it on the site? Does it get accepted?

Comment: No, I didn't think the issue was specific to the site.

Comment: Is there a way for me to test there without enrolling?

Comment: Looks like you'd need to create an account. (And when I try that, I get an error saying they don't run in Europe.)

Comment: The OP can let us know if this solved the problem.